# Update in Mac app store failed due to Hash Mismatch

Tags: mac-app-store

i submitted an update to mac app store for my app. However, when user tries to update, they get a hash mismatch error.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Much appreciate any replies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance change the App Name?

I've seen this on app descriptions before.

IMPORTANT MESSAGE TO EXISTING USERS: If you get an error message from the Mac App Store saying "hash mismatch" when you try to update: 1) Quit the Mac App Store 2) Quit FaceTab by opening the app window and clicking cmd + Q together, 3) Delete FaceTab from your Applications folder by dragging the icon to the Trash Can and then empty it, 4) Open the Mac App Store, go to the Purchases section and install MenuTab.

This is required in order to update to the new version due to the change in our app name